# Ternary assignment without "else" expression

Tags: java, ternary-operator, null-coalescing-operator, null-coalescing

Is it possible to use a shorthand for ternary *assignment* expressions of the type

```
boolean x = false;
// ... code ...
a = x ? b : a;   // Assigning a to a is pointless
a += x ? 1 : 0;  // Adding 0 to a is pointless
```

I'm thinking something along the lines of

```
a = x ? b;   // Assign b to a if x is true
a += x ? 1;  // Add 1 to a if x is true
```

Not that it saves a lot of typing, I'm just curious if something like this exists. I just recently discovered the [null coalesce operator](https://lornajane.net/posts/2015/new-in-php-7-null-coalesce-operator) in PHP 7, which does something kind of similar. To me it looks much cleaner than

```
if( x ) a = b;
if( x ) a += 1;
```

since these are assignments, and using a ternary expression looks more natural when reading from left to right. The supposed duplicate question isn't about assignments specifically, which in my opinion are a special use case of the ternary operator.

Comment: Use the `if` statement. That's why Java provides it.

Comment: By the way, Java is a pragmatic language which tries to avoid alias and multiple choices for the user; instead, it focuses on simplicity (even though it may seem strange to someone reading this comment, but this is the feeling that I've regarding Java after having used it for a few years).

Comment: What stops you from including that very same line inside one of your Java classes and checking by yourself that it doesn't compile?

Comment: @walen Nothing stops me from doing that, and I actually have - it gives me a syntax error. I'm not asking if the provided _hypothetical_ examples compile or not, I'm asking if there is any such language construct in Java. What's stopping you from actually thinking for a second about what the question is before posting useless comments?

Comment: The answer to your question is "No, Java has no conditional assignment operator." You seem to be confusing conditional assignments with conditional values.  `a = x ? b : a` is an unconditional assignment, `a` is always assigned the value of the ternary operator `x ? b : a`.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is **not** supported by Java.

From the official oracle doc:

> Another conditional operator is ?:, which can be thought of as shorthand for an if-then-else statement (discussed in the Control Flow Statements section of this lesson).
>   This operator is also known as the ternary operator because it uses three operands.
>   In the following example, this operator should be read as: "If someCondition is true, assign the value of value1 to result. Otherwise, assign the value of value2 to result."
>
> The following program, ConditionalDemo2, tests the ?: operator:

```
class ConditionalDemo2 {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int value1 = 1;
        int value2 = 2;
        int result;
        boolean someCondition = true;
        result = someCondition ? value1 : value2;

        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

> Because someCondition is true, this program prints "1" to the screen.
>   Use the ?: operator instead of an if-then-else statement if it makes your code more readable;
>   for example, when the expressions are compact and without side-effects (such as assignments).

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html